# Using mailgun API How can I use pagination between log events to have the total record

Tags: javascript, curl, mailgun

I am trying to query all events of the certain Tag on mailgun using the API, but the event query have limit record by page, so, how can I use the next url to save second page into a file.
I am currently using curl for it.
Thanks

Hello all,
I could did it using same structure that the original query, but changing Url to the one provide by next. You can do this until [Items] be zero, then you know you reach the final of you records

curl --user "api:key-123xxxxxx890" -G [next url here] -o some_text.txt

hope this help

Answer (score 1):

What also works well is to start a while back (eg. 15 min) with ascending=yes and limit=300 (the maximum). Then look for the last item time-stamp and restart from there. Repeat until no items are returned.